# Visual Studio Remote Debugger problem with the authentication

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging

I have a strange problem with the VS 2015 remote debugger.
So, in short:
To connect to the remote debugger, I need to enter username and password in a prompt window, which appears on the machine where the VS is started. When I enter the credentials for the user that is logged on the virtual machine, everything works fine.

The problem is, that the prompt does not appear!

And after many attempts to start, sometimes it appears and I can enter the credentials and use it.
But on the next day, it forgets that and I need again to try many times, until that window appears to enter the username and password. And today I am trying for 1-2 hours so far and it does not appear.

So, does anyone has the same problem? And is there some fix or some logical explanation, what this problem could be?